# QUnit test fails when document-ready block is declared inside the function being tested (IIFE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I'm building a web widget with jQuery based on this post but with a few improvements: http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/

Now I started writing some tests but they are failing and I believe it has something to do with me declaring a document-ready block inside the function, as suggested in the link above.

Here is a stripped down version of the widget:

```
var MyWidget = (function(w, d, $, undefined){

    var _getContent = function () {
        return 'My Widget Content';
    }

    var render = function (){
        $(function(){
            var content = _getContent();
            $('#container').html(content);
        });
    }

    return {
        render: render
    }

})(window, document, jQuery, undefined);
```

Here is the test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>MyWidget Tests</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/qunit/qunit/qunit.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="qunit"></div>
    <div id="qunit-fixture">
        <div id="container"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/qunit/qunit/qunit.js"></script>
    <script src="mywidget.js"></script>

    <script>
        QUnit.test('Test Content', function(assert){
            MyWidget.render();

            assert.equal($('#container').html(), 'My Widget Content');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the result:

[image]

However, when I delete the `$(function(){` code, then the test pass.

Any ideas what is happenning?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, my first guess is that jQuery's [wrapper around DOMContentLoaded](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) is somehow not being triggered because the event has already occurred and QUnit is somehow preventing the delayed execution of the event handler. Tricky thing... and should be easily testable outside of your widget thing. Could be a bug in QUnit though. I'll see if I can reproduce outside of your widget.

Comment: If you were to do this, would you do it differently?

Comment: I probably wouldn't do a `ready` function in my widget at all. I'd rely on the code _using_ my widget to do the `ready` stuff. Imagine that you have an app with 30 widgets... do they all need their own `ready` event handler? Probably not.

Comment: Agree but I think there are cases when this solution is acceptable (it's a simple widget that will get some HTML content via Ajax and append it at a div container). I wanted it to be self-contained and simple to configure with less markup. This must be a QUnit bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured out what the issue is. I should have seen it earlier. Even though your `render` function is being called *after* the document is ready (since the test calls it at the bottom), it is **still asynchronous** because of the `ready` handler you use (`$(function() {}`). As such, you will have to make your test asynchronous. Additionally, you will have to either (a) create some mechanism in your widget to notify the calling code that it is complete (like a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), or [jQuery's `Deferred`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/)); or (b) you will need to *also* use a `ready` handler in your test. Here is a test that works with your source code (and a [JSBin to see it](https://jsbin.com/bequcebuto/edit?html,output)):

```
QUnit.test('Test Content', function(assert){
  var done = assert.async();
  MyWidget.render();
  $(function() {
    assert.equal($('#container').html(), 'My Widget Content');
    done();
  });
});
```

If you wanted to go the jQuery Deferred route, you could do something like this in your `render` source:

```
var render = function (){
    var defObj = jQuery.Deferred();
    $(function(){
        var content = _getContent();
        $('#container').html(content);
        defObj.resolve();
    });
    return defObj;
}
```

Then in your test you would essentially do what I have in the test example above, only with Promise handlers:

```
QUnit.test('Test Content', function(assert){
  var done = assert.async();
  MyWidget.render()
    .then(function() {
      assert.equal($('#container').html(), 'My Widget Content');
      done();
    })
    .fail(done);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to research and come with a solution. It totally makes sense now though not so elegant I'll go with the first option cause it's the simplest among the other two. Thanks!